# When installing SQL Server 2016, the option to select standalong Polybase is disabled

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016

While installing a new installation of SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition, I was looking to enable Polybase.  As a first time out I wanted to install it as a standalone server, however, the option is disabled.  All of the online instructions or bloggers who've written about the install just say, select standalone.

This is on a newly installed Microsoft Server 2012R2 installation.

Anyone have any idea how to get the option to be enabled?
[image]

Comment: Random thought - do you have the pre-reqs, in particular Java installed? Also, I believe it's only a Ent Ed feature (not dev or standard)

Comment: egad... "...using PolyBase, which requires single Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition as head node.​​"

Comment: Not that familiar with Polybase but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx  - "Head Node" is Enterprise only

Answer (score 0):

In tiny print it does declare at the bottom of a footnote, that a head node is required, and that has to be Enterprise Edition.

Comment: ..in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying 'Beware of the Leopard.”